# Problem with For (or ForAll) loop in algorithm/algpseudocode: missing $ inserted

Tags: algorithms, algpseudocode

I currently have a problem I can't resolve. Here is my code :

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Feedback system}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State $expert$: object describing the expert (name, laterality and path to data)
\State $student$: object describing the student (name, laterality and path to data)
\Procedure{Feedback}{$expert$, $student$}
    \State $D_{exp} \gets$ all data from $expert$
    \State $D_{std} \gets$ all data from $student$
    \State $P \gets$ all the data to process for each problem

    \If{$normalisation$ == true}
        \State $P \gets$ normalised($P$)
    \EndIf
    \State $X_{d_{exp}} \gets$ expert's data repartition

    \ForAll{$p_i$ in $P$}
        \State $d_{exp} \gets$ get_data($p_i$, $X_{d_{exp}}$)
    \EndFor 

    \State clustering_result $\gets$ run_clustering
    \State student_centroid $\gets$ get_centroid($D_{std}$)

 \EndProcedure
 \end{algorithmic}
 \label{algorithm_Feedback}
\end{algorithm}
```

My import are

```
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing, dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocode}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{colortbl}
```

My problem is located at the ForAll loop. Basically, it tells me that I have a missing $ at the next line. If I delete all the code after the `\ForAll`, even the `\State` in the `ForAll` loop (and keep the `\EndFor` obviously), it compiles without any problem. I tried deleting only the `\State` inside the `ForAll` loop, or the `\State`s after the `\EndFor`, but with no success.

Long story short, this works

```
\ForAll{$p_i$ in $P$}
\EndFor
```

And this doesn't

```
\ForAll{$p_i$ in $P$}
    \State $d_{exp} \gets$ get_data($p_i$, $X_{d_{exp}}$)
\EndFor
```

```
\ForAll{$p_i$ in $P$}
    \State $d_{exp} \gets$ get_data($p_i$, $X_{d_{exp}}$)
\EndFor 

\State clustering_result $\gets$ run_clustering
\State student_centroid $\gets$ get_centroid($D_{std}$)
```

Can someone point out to me what seems to be the problem? I really don't get it, and I think my syntax is ok? I haven't found someone with the same problem as me. Sorry if it has been already answered or if the mistake is really obvious and stupid.

Cheers

EDIT: here is a compilable example:

```
\documentclass[
  % Replace twoside with oneside if you are printing your thesis on a single side
  % of the paper, or for viewing on screen.
  %oneside,
  oneside,
  11pt, a4paper,
  footinclude=true,
  headinclude=true,
  cleardoublepage=empty
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing, dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocode}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\title{Giga titre qui tue et qui donne envie de lire alors qu'en fait c'est chiant}
\author{Quentin Couland\\ Directeur de thèse : \textbf{Sébastien George}\\Co-encadrant : \textbf{Ludovic Hamon}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Feedback system}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State $expert$: object describing the expert (name, laterality and path to data)
\State $student$: object describing the student (name, laterality and path to data)
\Procedure{Feedback}{$expert$, $student$}
    \State $D_{exp} \gets$ all data from $expert$
    \State $D_{std} \gets$ all data from $student$
    \State $P \gets$ all the data to process for each problem

    \If{$normalisation$ == true}
        \State $P \gets$ normalised($P$)
    \EndIf
    \State $X_{d_{exp}} \gets$ expert's data repartition

    \ForAll{$p_i$ in $P$}
        \State $d_{exp} \gets$ get_data($p_i$, $X_{d_{exp}}$)
    \EndFor 

    \State clustering_result $\gets$ run_clustering
    \State student_centroid $\gets$ get_centroid($D_{std}$)

 \EndProcedure
 \end{algorithmic}
 \label{algorithm_Feedback}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your example compilable

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I added what should be a compilable version (it works on my computer at least).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do `\_`in textmode.

It needs to be:

```latex
\State $d_{exp} \gets$ get\_data($p_i$, $X_{d_{exp}}$)
```

instead of

```latex
\State $d_{exp} \gets$ get_data($p_i$, $X_{d_{exp}}$)
```

```latex
\documentclass[
  % Replace twoside with oneside if you are printing your thesis on a single side
  % of the paper, or for viewing on screen.
  %oneside,
  oneside,
  11pt, a4paper,
  footinclude=true,
  headinclude=true,
  cleardoublepage=empty
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing, dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocode}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\title{Giga titre qui tue et qui donne envie de lire alors qu'en fait c'est chiant}
\author{Quentin Couland\\ Directeur de thèse : \textbf{Sébastien George}\\Co-encadrant : \textbf{Ludovic Hamon}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Feedback system}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State $expert$: object describing the expert (name, laterality and path to data)
\State $student$: object describing the student (name, laterality and path to data)
\Procedure{Feedback}{$expert$, $student$}
    \State $D_{exp} \gets$ all data from $expert$
    \State $D_{std} \gets$ all data from $student$
    \State $P \gets$ all the data to process for each problem

    \If{$normalisation$ == true}
        \State $P \gets$ normalised($P$)
    \EndIf
    \State $X_{d_{exp}} \gets$ expert's data repartition

    \ForAll{$p_i$ in $P$}
        \State $d_{exp} \gets$ get\_data($p_i$, $X_{d_{exp}}$)
    \EndFor 

    \State clustering\_result $\gets$ run\_clustering
    \State student\_centroid $\gets$ get\_centroid($D_{std}$)

 \EndProcedure
 \end{algorithmic}
 \label{algorithm_Feedback}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Wow thanks a lot, my lack of knowledge in the math mode was the biggest problem here. Thanks again!